# Using the erdc package on Mac OS X

Tags: fonts, installing, texlive, mactex, mac

I have the [MacTeX-2012 Distribution](http://tug.org/mactex/) installed on my MacBook Pro running OS X 10.8.3 Mountain Lion. Opening [TeX Live Update](https://code.google.com/p/mactlmgr/), I see that the erdc package is installed. However, as stated in `erdc.pdf`, [mathgifg](http://ctan.math.utah.edu/ctan/tex-archive/fonts/mathgifg/) is required to provide access to Microsoft Georgia and ITC Franklin Gothic fonts, but [mathgifg](http://ctan.math.utah.edu/ctan/tex-archive/fonts/mathgifg/) isn't available via [TeX Live Update](https://code.google.com/p/mactlmgr/).

### Questions

1. How can I install [mathgifg](http://ctan.math.utah.edu/ctan/tex-archive/fonts/mathgifg/) on OS X, since it isn't available on [TeX Live Update](https://code.google.com/p/mactlmgr/)?
2. Is it possible to install the Microsoft Georgia and ITC Franklin Goth fonts on OS X, or are they available only on Windows?
3. How can I install the fonts for use with [MacTeX-2012](http://tug.org/mactex/)?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The font families `Georgia` (in "Regular" and "Bold" weights, with upright and italic shapes) and `Franklin Gothic` (in "Book" and "Medium" weights, also with upright and italic shapes), but not `ITC Franklin Gothic`, should be pre-installed on your MacOS X system. `ITC Franklin Gothic` is a clone of `Franklin Gothic`; I doubt you'll be able to detect visually meaningful differences between them.

Since `Georgia` and `Franklin Gothic Book` are system fonts, you can access them directly -- as is shown in the MWE below -- if you're willing to run `LuaLaTeX` rather than `pdfLaTeX`.

If you are willing to run `LuaLaTeX` (and I can't imagine why you wouldn't) on your `.tex` files, the only remaining function of the `mathgifg` package is to provide a math font family that meshes with the `Georgia` text font. (Aside: To set up the `mathgifg` package on your system, you'd download the `.ins` and `.dtx` files from, e.g., http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/mathgifg, to a scratch folder, and run LaTEX on `mathgifg.ins` to generate the file `mathgifg.sty`. Copy the style file either to the folder where your main `.tex` file is located or to a folder that's searched by MacTeX2012. After that, run `sudo texhash` to update TeX's filename database.)

In the MWE below, I suggest using `XITS Math` (a Times Roman clone) as the math font, as `Georgia` is at least somewhat based on `Times Roman`. `XITS Math` certainly isn't perfect, but using it is a lot better than, say, Computer Modern Math. Perhaps another person can suggest a math font that harmonizes better `Georgia`. Because `Georgia` is a font with both a large x-height and a large caps-height relative to its nominal or point size, I suggest you use the `Scale=MatchUppercase` option when setting the sans font, and the option `Scale=MatchLowercase` for the math font. (For more on what these options do, I recommend you study the [user guide](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/xetex/latex/fontspec/) of the `fontspec` manual.)

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{erdc}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Georgia}
\setsansfont[Scale=MatchUppercase]{Franklin Gothic Book}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont[Scale=MatchLowercase]{XITS Math}
\begin{document}
Hello World.
$E=mc^2$.
\textsf{Hello World.}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[Mico's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/102836/1155) got me on the right track, so I've accepted his answer. However, there were a few differences, so here are the exact steps that I took.

1. Download the `mathgifg` package [zip archive from ctan](http://mirrors.ctan.org/fonts/mathgifg.zip) to `~/Downloads/`.
2. Using Finder, I double-clicked `~/Downloads/mathgifg/mathgifg.ins` to open it with [TeXShop](http://pages.uoregon.edu/koch/texshop/).
3. Press `Typeset` in [TeXShop](http://pages.uoregon.edu/koch/texshop/) to generate `mathgifg.sty`.
   [image: TeXShop typesetting <code>mathgifg.ins</code>]
4. Open Terminal and switch directories using `cd ~/Library/texmf`
5. Create the necessary directory to store your `.sty` files using `mkdir -p tex/latex`
6. Copy the `mathgifg.sty` file using `cp ~/Downloads/mathgifg/mathgifg.sty ~/Library/texmf/tex/latex/` — By copying the `.sty` file here, we don't have to run `sudo texhash` to update TeX's filename database.
7. Open the Preferences pane in [Latexian](http://tacosw.com/latexian/) and then change the File Type for `.tex` files to XeTeX — This is the [LaTeX](http://www.latex-project.org) editor that I use, and it doesn't support [LuaLaTeX](http://www.luatex.org), but it does allow using [XeLaTeX](http://www.xelatex.org) for processing. Even though [Latexian](http://tacosw.com/latexian/) says XeTeX in the preferences, it uses [XeLaTeX](http://www.xelatex.org) for processing.
   [image: Latexian File Type Preferences]
8. Once I commented out the `\setmathfont[Scale=MatchLowercase]{XITS Math}` command, I was then able to process Mico's [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/1155).
   [image: Latexian processing Mico's MWE]
9. Process the `sample.tex` file included with the [erdc](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/erdc) package.
   [image: Latexian processing erdc]
10. Success!