# How to install mathgifg package

Tags: packages, installing

How do I install the [`mathgifg` package](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/mathgifg) on Mac with MacTeX 2013 and Windows with TeX Live 2013? I am using `pdflatex` so  [Using the erdc package on Mac OS X](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/102832/using-the-erdc-package-on-mac-os-x) does not solve my problem.

Comment: Related: [Using the erdc with MiKTeX on Windows (trouble with mathgifg and font setup)](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/49076)

Comment: I suppose its related but it doesn't help me any since none of the instructions are applicable to MacTeX 2013 nor the Mac operating system....

Comment: If my answer also helps with http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/129815/how-to-install-mathgifg-sty-package-on-windows-with-tex-live-2013, let me know and I'll dupe the other question to this one

Comment: But please note that this question specifically asked about the Mac

Comment: Go ahead and dupe it, I haven't checked on Windows yet but I presume it should work since it did on Mac

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `mathgifg` package provides LaTeX support for the Georgia and Franklin Gothic font familes, but not the fonts themselves. The latter are [available commercially](http://www.ascenderfonts.com/): licensing issues when having to convert font formats are non-trivial, so I will simply assume you have an appropriately-licensed copy.

There are essentially three stages to installing the fonts: converting from TrueType of Adobe format, installing the necessary files locally and making (La)TeX aware of them.
There are some slight variations in how these are done depending on the operating system and TeX system you use: I will try to cover the various options! Note also that if your license covers it, you only have to do the conversion once to install on multiple systems.

Note that font installation is non-trivial and needs some experience with the Command Line/Terminal.

### 1. Conversion of files

The first thing necessary is to get hold of a copy of [`ttf2pt1`](http://ttf2pt1.sourceforge.net/), which is needed to do the conversion. It's available on SourceForge in [source format](http://prdownloads.sourceforge.net/ttf2pt1/ttf2pt1-3.4.4.tgz) (Mac or Linux) or as [precompiled binary](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/downlinks/ttf2pt1.php) (Windows). For Mac/Linux users, simply unzip the archive, and using the Terminal run

```
make all
```

inside the folder: this should produce an executable `ttf2pt1`. The Windows installer puts the binary inside `C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\bin\` as `ttf2pt1.exe`. In either case, the easiest way to work is to copy this binary to where we will do the next step: the conversion itself. I'll assume you create a temporary folder on your Desktop called `font-convert`: put the executable there.

The next step is to collect up the font (`.ttf`) files and give them the correct names. You don't necessarily have to have all of the fonts, only those you will use. There is a table of the font file names in the [`mathgifg` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/fonts/mathgifg/mathgifg.pdf). On my Windows systems I have the Georgia and the 'basic' Franklin Gothic files with the 'correct' names, while on my Mac I have the same files but with longer 'descriptive' names. In any case, the safest approach is to *copy* the files to our `font-convert` folder, then rename if required.

We now need the Terminal/Command prompt, and to change to the `font-convert` folder. There, you need to do

```
./ttf2pt1 -a -b <filename>
```

for each font file: for example `<filename>` will be `georgia.ttf` for the Georgia roman font. This will create a `.pfb` and a `.afm` file for each `.ttf` file. Once you've done that, we ill not need the `.ttf` (or `.afm`) files further: it is the `.pfb` files that are important.

### 2. Installation of files

The second stage of the process is to install the fonts and support files locally. There is a decision to make here: install only for a single user or for all users on the computer. There are technical issues in installing for a single user, so I'll assume you will add for all users (this probably needs Admin/root access).

The location to put the font files depends on your operating system and TeX system: we need to know where your 'local texmf tree' is:

- TeX Live on Linux/Mac: `/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local`
- TeX Live on Windows: `C:\texlive\texmf-local` (assuming a standard installation location)
- MiKTeX: see [Create a local texmf tree in MiKTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/69483/create-a-local-texmf-tree-in-miktex): you will need to create a new tree in 'Admin' mode if you have a mutli-user installation

I'll refer to that folder as '`<localtexmf>`'. Inside it, you need to create two folders

```
fonts/type1/microsoft/georgia
fonts/type1/itc/franklingothic
```

and copy the `.pfb` files into the appropriate places.

You now need the LaTeX support files: these are best downloaded as a 'ready to go' file [`mathgifg.tds.zip`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/install/fonts/mathgifg.tds.zip). If you unzip this, you'll find it contains a lot of files. They need to go inside `<localtexmf>` in their respective folders (stuff in the `fonts` folder needs to go in the `<localtexmf>/fonts` directory, stuff in the `tex` folder needs to go in the `<localtexmf>/tex` directory, etc.), so for example you end up with

```
<localtexmf>/tex/latex/mathgifg/mathgifg.sty
<localtexmf>/tex/latex/mathgifg/omlzifg.fd
...
<localtexmf>/fonts/afm/microsoft/georgia/georgia.afm
...
```

You don't have to install the files in the `doc` folder, although they may be handy later.

You then need to make sure TeX can find the files. For TeX Live, as `root`/Admin do `texhash <localtexmf>` (with correct folder name). For MiKTeX, use `initexmf --admin --update-fndb=<localtexmf>` as Admin, again filling in the appropriate folder name. (If you have a single user MiKTeX installation, you don't need the `--admin` option here or in the instructions below.)

### 3. Updating maps

The final step is to enable TeX to find the fonts: this is done by updating the map files.

For TeX Live/MacTeX, at the Terminal append

```
Map mathgifg.map
```

to the file

```
<localtexmf>/web2c/updmap.cfg
```

using a text editor (create the file if it does not already exist). Then run

```
updmap-sys
```

Both steps are to be performed using `sudo` for Linux/Mac or an Administrator Command Prompt on Windows.

For MiKTeX at the (Admin) Command Prompt do

```
initexmf --admin --edit-config-file updmap
```

and add the line

```
Map mathgifg.map
```

then after saving the file run

```
initexmf --admin --mkmaps
```

again as Admin.

If all has worked, you should now be able to do `\usepackge{mathgifg}` and everything should work.

Comment: I usually recommend *never* installing fonts in the personal tree, at least for TeX Live; the correct place is the local tree, otherwise any change to fonts installed by the package manager will require running manually `updmap`. (I can't talk about MiKTeX.)

Comment: To install `ttf2pt1` on OS X, you can also use the [Homebrew](http://brew.sh) command `brew install ttf2pt1`

Comment: @MatthewRankin As it's a one-file download, I think just grabbing the script is easier (unless you are a hardcore Homebrew user).

Comment: Note that if you use pdflatex, you can use the truetype without converting to type1 which is more likely to be compatible with the licensing. You still need to generate `.tfm` files but that is less likely to count as converting the fonts themselves.