# Font shape errors in .cls file template

Tags: font-encodings

I'm using a LaTeX template I found [here](https://www.sharelatex.com/templates/journals/reports_by_us_army_corps_of_engieneers/) which looks lovely, but won't accept any in-line formatting, such as \textbf{bolded text}. When I generate the pdf I get errors such as:

```
No file T1xjgi.fd
```

and

```
Font shape `OML/zifg/k/n' undefined(Font) using `OML/cmm/m/it' instead
```

and

```
Font shape `T1/xifg/k/n' undefined(Font) using `T1/xifg/m/n' instead
```

I also suspect that the formatting specified in the .cls document isn't being applied all the time.

I've been searching through the .cls document and I believe the error is somewhere in the top-ish area, but I'm at a a loss for where it is:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{erdc}
[2009/07/22 v1.1 Typesetting Technical Information Reports of
the Engineer Research and Development Center (ERDC),
US Army Corps of Engineers]
\long\def\erdc@size@warning#1{%
  \ClassWarning{erdc}{Size-changing option #1 will not be
    honored}}%
\DeclareOption{8pt}{\erdc@size@warning{\CurrentOption}}%
\DeclareOption{9pt}{\erdc@size@warning{\CurrentOption}}%
\DeclareOption{10pt}{\erdc@size@warning{\CurrentOption}}%
\DeclareOption{11pt}{\erdc@size@warning{\CurrentOption}}%
\DeclareOption{12pt}{\erdc@size@warning{\CurrentOption}}%
\DeclareOption*{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{report}}
\ProcessOptions\relax
\LoadClass[12pt,twoside]{report}
\RequirePackage{graphicx,color,caption,longtable}
\RequirePackage{dcolumn}
\RequirePackage{natbib}
\renewcommand{\bibfont}{\fontsize{10pt}{12pt}\selectfont}
\setlength{\bibhang}{0.5in}
\setlength{\bibsep}{12pt}
\RequirePackage{amsmath}
\RequirePackage[originalcommands]{ragged2e}
\setlength\RaggedRightParindent{\parindent}
\RaggedRight
\renewcommand\normalsize{%
   \@setfontsize\normalsize\@xiipt{16}%
   \abovedisplayskip 16\p@ \@plus3\p@ \@minus7\p@
   \abovedisplayshortskip \z@ \@plus3\p@
   \belowdisplayshortskip 6.5\p@ \@plus3.5\p@ \@minus3\p@
   \belowdisplayskip \abovedisplayskip
   \let\@listi\@listI}
\normalsize
\usepackage{mathgifg}
\usepackage{courier}
\def\@laboratoryfont{%
  \sffamily\bfseries\fontsize{22pt}{25pt}\selectfont}
\def\@reportnumfont{%
  \sffamily\bfseries\fontsize{18pt}{22pt}\selectfont}
\def\@programfont{%
  \sffamily\fontseries{k}\itshape\normalsize\selectfont}
\def\@titlefont{%
  \sffamily\fontseries{h}\fontsize{20pt}{25pt}\selectfont}
\def\@distributionfont{%
  \sffamily\fontseries{k}\fontsize{9pt}{11pt}\selectfont}
\def\@eqtagfont{\sffamily\bfseries\footnotesize}
\RequirePackage[letterpaper, top=1in, bottom=0.7in,
  left=1.5in, right=1.5in]{geometry}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. The template is linked above if you want to take a better look.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! The class uses the `mathgifg` package, that uses a proprietary font. See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/129819/how-to-install-mathgifg-package

Comment: Wow! Thanks for the fast and helpful info.

I don't want to deal with proprietary fonts, so I just disabled the mathgifg package and the formatting seems to be working now. 

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The class uses the package `mathgifg` which supports the Georgia and Franklin Gothic ITC fonts; the latter is not free, see [How to install mathgifg package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/129819/how-to-install-mathgifg-package)

You should comment out the call to the package and, perhaps, change the

```
\fontseries{k}
\fontseries{h}
```

commands to something else. Possibly `k` should be `b`, but I have no idea of what can substitute `h`.