# How to properly include fonts for mathgifg package

Tags: fonts, pdftex, texlive, mactex

I installed the mathgifg package according to this guide:

[How to install mathgifg package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/129819/how-to-install-mathgifg-package) as well as the [mathgifg documentation](ftp://ftp.rrzn.uni-hannover.de/pub/mirror/tex-archive/fonts/mathgifg/mathgifg.pdf).

For typesetting I am using the MacTex 2013 distribution and pdftex.
Now I am testing the installation with a basic version of the mathgifg sample file since I am only interested in using Franklin Gothic Fonts in my documents:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum,url}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{mathgifg,amsfonts,amsmath}
\usepackage{ifpdf}
\ifpdf
     \pdfmapfile{+mathgifg.map}
\fi

\newcounter{lipsumnum}
\setcounter{lipsumnum}{1}

\newcommand{\samplefont}[2]{{#1\selectfont #2: 
0123456789, \$20, \texteuro30, \pounds60.
Na\"ive \AE sop's \OE uvres in fran\c cais were my first reading.
\lipsum[\value{lipsumnum}]\stepcounter{lipsumnum}\par}}

\begin{document}

\section{Text Tests}
\label{sec:text}

%\samplefont{\sffamily\fontseries{k}}{Franklin Gothic Book}
\samplefont{\sffamily\fontseries{k}\itshape}{Franklin Gothic Book Italic}

\end{document}
```

As you can see I am testing the Franklin Gothic Book and the corresponding italic fonts, commenting out the not used option.
When I use the Franklin Gothic Book option I get the following error:

```
!pdfTeX error: /usr/local/texlive/2013/bin/x86_64-darwin/pdflatex (file georgia.pfb): cannot open Type 1 font file for reading
==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

I do not know why pdftex wants to use georgia.pfb for this.
When I use the Italic option I get the following error:

```
!pdfTeX error: /usr/local/texlive/2013/bin/x86_64-darwin/pdflatex (file frabkit.pfb): cannot open Type 1 font file for reading
 ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

The frabkit.pbf is definitely available in /usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/fonts/type1/itc/franklingothic

During installation of the mathgifg package I had some issues with the correct folders. The texmf-local folder did not exist in /usr/local/texlive, so I created it according to the guide. However, I am not sure if this is the correct way, since the texlive folder does also contain the various MacTex distributions in folders corresponding to the version (2012, 2013, 2014) and I am also not sure if the mathgifg package does require all Georgia and Franklin Gothic Fonts to work (I just installed two).

Any advice is very welcome.

UPDATE:
I deleted the lines

```
\ifpdf
  \pdfmapfile{+mathgifg.map}
\fi
```

according to the comments. The error now is:

```
!pdfTeX error: /usr/local/texlive/2013/bin/x86_64-darwin/pdflatex (file xifgki8r): Font xifgki8r at 600 not found
```

I am using Texpad 1.7.9 for editing and typesetting.

Comment: You can find out the location of texmflocal with `kpsewhich -expand-var=$TEXMFLOCAL` in a terminal.

Comment: That's the right place. If you followed the instructions Joseph Wright posted, you don't need the `\pdfmapfile` line, and if you've converted the fonts, it doesn't matter whether you're using pdfTeX or not. What does `kpsewhich frabkit.pfb` give?

Comment: @cfr `kpsewhich frabkit.pfb` returns nothing. `kpsewhich -expand-var=$TEXMFLOCAL`returns an empty line.

Comment: That command returns an empty line for me, too, so I think that's expected. I think probably @UlrikeFischer meant to suggest `kpsewhich -var=TEXMFLOCAL`. The fact that the `kpsewhich` command returns nothing means that the fonts maybe in the right place but are not installed correctly. Did you run `mktexlsr`? You probably need to do this as root (e.g. with `sudo`).

Comment: @cfr Ok, that one returned `/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local`, which is exactly the folder where I put the data according to the guide. I also did run `mktexlsr` which updated several folders. However, the same errors occur. It now seems that it's always complaining about the `georgia.pfb`, although I am using the FG fonts.

Comment: Well for me (on windows) `kpsewhich --expand-var=$TEXMFLOCAL` works. Are you sure that you have the .pfb?

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer I have the `frank.pfb` and `framd.pfb` in the folder mentioned in the question. Does the package need all fonts that it supports for to work? If yes, could I compensate with just copy pasting a standard font and renaming it to the missing fonts? I am just interested in the Franklin Gothic fonts.

Comment: Well your document seems to look for frabkit.pfb (and frabk.pfb if you uncomment the line). So you need these files -- or you must adapt the map-file (and hope that the metrics of your pfb are suitable).

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer Sorry, auto correction typo. `frabk.pbf`and `framd.pbf`are there. I also duplicated the frabk.pbf and renamed it to `frabkit.pbf`just for testing. That did't work either.

Comment: The style sets  \rmfamily to georgia and so e.g. the page number and your section request it. Remove the sty and try simply `{\fontfamily{xifg}\fontseries{k}\selectfont abc}`

Comment: @UlrikeFischer On Linux, `kpsewhich --expand-var=$TEXMFLOCAL` returns nothing.